# Load shell color codes from YAML file

Tags: python, shell, colors, ruamel.yaml

### How can i load a color code for my shell from a yaml file with ruamel yaml?##

I am able to change the color in my shell via python with some very simple instructions:

```
R = "\033[0;31;40m"
print(R+"TEST")
```

This outputs "TEST" in the color red. (I did not reset the style for simplicity)

I have the following YAML file:

```
colors:
  red : \033[0;31;40m
```

I try to achieve the same thing loading the color code from a YAML file, but it literally outputs `\033[0;31;40mTEST`. Here is my code. (I played around with different load types, quotes, escaping it, but I can't seem to get it working. I understand this happens for security reasons.)

```
import ruamel.yaml

path_to_config = "config/config.yml"

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ="safe")

with open(path_to_inventory) as fpi:
    config = yaml.load(fpi)

print(config["colors"]["red"]+"TEST")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash only has a special meaning in YAML if it is between double quotes. To know what your YAML should look like it is best to dump the result you want to have:

```
yaml.dump("\033[0;31;40m", sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
"\e[0;31;40m"
```

So with:

```
colors:
  red : "\e[0;31;40m"
```

you should be fine.

The recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2007.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i fixed the "type" typo. 
I already tried double quotes, but by doing so, `\0` get's intrepreted as a special char.
If i escape \ it with \\ i am back at the literal output `\033[0;31;40m`.

Comment: Sorry I only looked at the lloaded value, didni't compare it for equality to your Python string. I updated my answer.

Comment: Instead of the YAML escape sequence `\e`, you can also use the 8bit Unicode char sequence `\x1B`

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply, this solves my problem.
(I updated the file extension, so thanks for that too)
(I would love to upvote your solution, but it i guess i'll have to earn that privilege first)

Comment: You'll earn the privilege to upvote soon enough  ;-)